# What does this snippet in C++ do?

Tags: c++

What does this snippet of C++ code do? I've tried to read many sources about pointers but I just can't get my head around it.

```
long address = *((long *)(another_address + 0x0));
int(*function)() = (int(*)())address;
```

Edit: another_address is a vtable address. I'm trying to port this to Python, and was actually asking about how the pointer stuff works (in the snippet).

Comment: It manually parses a vtable, would be my guess. `another_address` is probably a vtable pointer - a pointer to an array of function pointers. The code extracts the address in slot 0 of that vtable, and casts it to a function pointer, that could be called.

Comment: Ah sorry, another_address is an address to a vtable yes. The code is meant to get a virtual function from a vtable. I'm trying to port this to Python, so I was actually asking how the pointer stuff works - should probably have included this in my question.

Comment: The pointer stuff works fine. I suppose I don't understand the question. Is there something in particular that's unclear?

Answer (score 1):

`(another_address + 0x0)` evaluates to `another_address`, then is cast to `long*`, then dereferenced.

`(int(*)()) address` casts `address` to a function that takes no arguments and returns an `int`, it is then assigned to `function` with the same signature.